# parse error in formulas with a reference to another sheet, when the other sheet is recreated

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I got a parse error in formulas because this cell has a reference to another sheet. (like  =Sheet4!A1).
The problem arises when "Sheet4" is recreated during execution of apps script.

Manually clicking on the cell it is ok recalculated.

I want a way to recalculate references to external sheet programatically be apps script.

many thanks!

Comment: I believe your problem is, you delete the sheet and then create a new sheet with the same name.  Try instead to simply `.clear()` the sheet and then refill with the new data.

Comment: Thanks, but .clear does not reset the sheet to initial state. by example, the merged cells are not unmerged.

Comment: Did you look at [`.clear({ formatOnly: true, contentsOnly: true });`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear(Object))

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I looked but not tried, because .clear(true,true) =>"Clears the sheet of contents and/or format, as specified with the given advanced options." . It looks to be identical to .clear() =>"Clears the sheet of content and formatting information."

Comment: No I tested it with merge cells.  It will give a completely unformatted sheet.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The problem arise because the frezze was not cleared and interfered with .Clear. Only the non freezed areas was "cleared"

Comment: I make a ClearSheet function that reset the Freeze & .Clear.  " 
     sheet2Clear.setFrozenRows(0);
     sheet2Clear.setFrozenColumns(0);
     sheet2Clear.clear();"   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After evaluate the 3 proposed solutions. I believe all are ok, but I will choosed the way of "sheet.clear".
Trying .clear() I detected a interference with "freezed" rows and/or columns. The "freezed" areas are not "cleared"!
The solution adopted and tested, is to create a simple function :

```
 function ClearSheet(sheet2Clear) {
     sheet2Clear.setFrozenRows(0);
     sheet2Clear.setFrozenColumns(0);
     sheet2Clear.clear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your goal is to refresh the formula automatically. I see two ways to do it. You can choose whatever fits best for you.

**Solution1**

You mentioned that Sheet4 is recreated during execution of AppsScript. One solution is to add the following piece of code after the code which creates Sheet4.

Let's say your formula is present in Sheet1 which needs to be refreshed when Sheet4 is created/recreated.

```
// Assuming you would already have the spreadsheet object in a variable in existing code, 
// let's say ss.
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet1.getRange('A1').setValue('=Sheet4!A1');
```

This would refresh the formula.

**Solution2**

In case you want to do it separately without updating the existing code, you can update the formula using onChange trigger

You just need to manually run the below function "createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger" once. It will create a trigger to run refreshFormula whenever the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed.

```
function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('refreshFormula')
    .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}

function refreshFormula(e) {
  var changeType = e.changeType;
  // INSERT_GRID means when a new sheet is created in the spreadsheet
  if (changeType === "INSERT_GRID") {
    var spreadsheet = e.source;
    var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    sheet1.getRange('A1').setValue('=Sheet4!A1');
  }
}
```

Comment: A clever solutions for the way of delete/recreate sheet.. Not tested but looks OK. Thanks  @ab.it.gcp !